# Delete all div classes with Javascript

Tags: javascript, class

I have a question about to remove whole classes below here
like whole classes inside lists class including buttons. But it doesn't work tho.

I tried with the other simple codes, but it works as well.
I wonder if is there any way to solve this issue.
Thank you!

```
const test2 = document.getElementById("list-id");
test2.classList.remove("lists");

    
    <div class="lists" div id="list-id">

        <div class="board" div id="board-id">
            <div class="email-header"></div>
            <div class="promo-code">Promo Code</div>
            <div class="list" div id="box-1"><button id="1" onclick="deleteBox(this.id)">X</button></div>
            <div class="list" div id="box-2"><button id="2" onclick="deleteBox(this.id)">X</button></div>
            <div class="list" div id="box-3"><button id="3" onclick="deleteBox(this.id)">X</button></div>
            <div class="list" div id="box-4"><button id="4" onclick="deleteBox(this.id)">X</button></div>
            <div class="list" div id="box-5"><button id="5" onclick="deleteBox(this.id)">X</button></div>
            <div class="list" div id="box-6"><button id="6" onclick="deleteBox(this.id)">X</button></div>
            <div class="email-footer"></div>
        </div>

        <div class="list" div id="product-list">
            <h2>Product List</h2>
            <div class="list-item" div id="1" draggable="true"><button id="1" onclick="deleteProduct(this.id)">X</button></div>
            <div class="list-item" div id="2" draggable="true"><button id="2" onclick="deleteProduct(this.id)">X</button></div>
            <div class="list-item" div id="3" draggable="true"><button id="3" onclick="deleteProduct(this.id)">X</button></div>
            <div class="list-item" div id="4" draggable="true"><button id="4" onclick="deleteProduct(this.id)">X</button></div>
            <div class="list-item" div id="5" draggable="true"><button id="5" onclick="deleteProduct(this.id)">X</button></div>
            <div class="list-item" div id="6" draggable="true"><button id="6" onclick="deleteProduct(this.id)">X</button></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Please provide a properly detailed explanation of what you are expecting from this code and how it differs from expected. See [ask]

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
  let divs = Array.from(document.getElementsByTagName("div"));
  for (let div of divs) {
    div.className = "";
  }

})
```

Comment: nice, please upvote my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

To remove the visible class from the div element, you use the following code: const div = document.querySelector ('div'); div.classList.remove ('info'); Code language: JavaScript (javascript) The remove () method also allows you to remove multiple classes at once, like this:

If you want to remove classes from div you can use javascript for that.
just use query selector . for example (const removeclass=document.querySelector('list');
removeclass.classList.remove('list'));

if you want to remove all the class from list you can you this

Comment: Thank you for your information. It made me a lot of help with this issue! Thanks again!